# ¿Se puede hacer un contador en macros que me registre cuentas veces se ejecuta una macro?

Tags: excel, vba

Quisiera saber si se puede hacer un contador o un boolean que cambie cada vez que una macro es ejecutada, ya que necesito hacer un condicional que valida si una macro fue ejecutada para realizar cierta acción.

nota:
el contador será usado en una macro diferente, es decir en otro módulo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes utilizar un acumulador y asignarle un valor una vez terminadas las instrucciones y luego meter ese valor en una celda. Quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
    Sub mi_macro
    ...(instrucciones)...
    acumulador=acumulador+1
    Cells(100,100).value(acumulador)   // Se entiende 100,100 por asignar una celda que no esté en uso en la planilla. 
    End Sub
```

Luego vas a la celda(100,100) y tomas el valor.

Comment: Perfecto, de verdad muchas gracias, lo necesitaba ya que uso una macro que crea una tabla dinámica y genera un informe, pero tiene una opción de eliminar columnas y al realizar esto el rango de la tabla dinámica se alteraba y me tiraba problema por lo que necesitaba cambiar el rango según la columna que se eliminaba. así que uso un if y utilizo el contador para saber si la macro de eliminar se utilizo.

Answer (score 0):

Si el rango se te modifica podes utilizar una combinación de funciones para obtener el indice de la fila (o columna) donde se posiciona el cursor. 
Podes utilizar el "Selection.End(xlRight).Select" y "ActiveCell.Column". Investiga más sobre las variaciones de estos comandos y tal vez puedan servirte de mucha utilidad. yo uso: "Selection.End(xlDown).Select" y utilizo el "ActiveCell.Row" para obtener el indice de la ultima fila de la tabla dinámica.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el consejo, si aun ando investigando varias cosas de macros ya que apenas empiezo con el mundo del VBA, esta bueno eso de obtener el indice de la ultima fila de la tabla dinámica.

Comment: Yo aprendi con este tutorial.. Te dejo el Link... ojalá te sirva!  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hP9hTcrNkMw&list=PLTrK0ruIA5B_nry7VxZ97qrPCQKpG1RSn